# Cannot access the Box Application using API Key

Tags: box-api

I have created an application in Box and got an API Key, and then edited the redirect URL. But when I accessed through URL https://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key=APIKEY, I'm not getting a positive response, instead of I'm getting a response like:

```
<response>
<status>application_restricted</status>
</response>
```

Please provide me a solution to get access to the application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a commercial service, not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The V1 API has been [deprecated](https://cloud.app.box.com/s/uoc5cp3vkz6vr95mpsva) and will no longer provide authentication or file access. You need to migrate your application to the V2 API, which is [documented here](http://developers.box.com/get-started/).

Comment: Just want to add that Box has a terrible design on this. For the type of response OP got, Box's API actually returned a 200 status code. I don't think they get what OK actually means.

Comment: Robert, are you referring to the V1 or V2 API?

Comment: John, I am referring to V1 API. We had this issue earlier today.

Comment: can you please help me out to resolved this issue?
I am getting same <status> response.
**application_restricted**

Answer (score 0):

For accessing access_token using java sdk , You need to have following key values

1) clienId > Use Application console

2) client_secret > Use application console

3) code > Code value you will get using below link 
https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={your_client_id}&state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA

Replace your client id with original value. client id you will get from your apps.

And Follow steps and authorize you application using your credential.

after that it will redirect to   https://localhost/?state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA&code=sdsdsd3sdsdC0oGqOS2WgaFipZBdj

Copy code value

```
String clienId = "your client id ";

String client_secret = "your secret id"; 

String code = "sdsdsd3sdsdC0oGqOS2WgaFipZBdj"; // use above extracted  code value 
BoxAPIConnection con = new BoxAPIConnection(clienId,client_secret,code);

String accessToken = con.getAccessToken();

System.out.println("Accss_Token : " +accessToken);
```